# Is there a way to simplify conditionally adding values to an object with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dry

I have a node.js script where I'm adding keys to an object if either a local or global value exists. I feel as though there should be a good way to simplify this, but I'm not seeing it. Is there a way to make this code less verbose:

```
  var object = {
    defaultKey: defaultValue
  };

  // Add some conditional keys based on local and global settings
  // With local settings taking precedence
  if (local.firstSetting || firstSetting) {
    entry.firstSetting = local.firstSetting || firstSetting;
  }
  if (local.secondSetting || secondSetting) {
    entry.secondSetting = local.secondSetting || secondSetting;
  }
  if (local.thirdSetting || thirdSetting) {
    entry.thirdSetting = local.thirdSetting || thirdSetting;
  }
```

I've thought about adding all the keys to the object and just assigning them a value of `local.thirdSetting || thirdSetting`, but I don't think it would be smart to potentially have keys with an undefined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm doing now is this:

```
  var pick = require('lodash.pick');
  var identity = require('lodash.identity');

  var object = pick({
    defaultKey: defaultValue
    firstSetting: local.firstSetting || firstSetting,
    secondSetting: local.secondSetting || secondSetting,
    thirdSetting: local.thirdSetting || thirdSetting
  }, identity);
```

This will filter all undefined values (or falsy values to be precise) from the object.

Answer (score 3):

There is shared functionality here which can be refactored into a function.

```
function getSetting(name) {
    var setting = local[name] || globals[name] || entry[name];
    if(setting) {
        entry[name] = setting;
    }
}

getSetting('firstSetting');
getSetting('secondSetting');
getSetting('thirdSetting');
```

Comment: @jfriend00 that's incorrect. Try this in node: `(function() {console.log(this);})()`. You'll see that `this` refers to the global object which contains all globals.

Comment: If you want to refer to globals in node.js, use the `globals` object.  Using `this` to implicitly access globals is very bad practice as it will break in all sorts of cases like in a method call, like in any function calls using strict mode, etc...  If you mean to access globals, then use the `globals` object.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. I have edited accordingly. Thanks @jfriend00.

Comment: Now, all that fixed, how can you tell that `firstSetting` is actually a global?  I can't see that for sure in the OP's code.  It is a variable in parent scope, but it is not clear whether it is just a module variable (which is not a global), a variable in a parent scope, a variable in the current scope or what.  Unless it's a property of some object, you'd have to pass it in rather than access it like you are.

Comment: It is unclear in the code, but the question states that it could be both: _"if either a local or global value exists."_ Presumably by `local` they mean _on the `local` object_. But you're right, whether they mean _on the `globals` object_ or not is unclear. @DrMister, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Modification of Jaromanda X's anwer:

```
var t;
if( t = local.firstSetting  || firstSetting  )  entry.firstSetting  = t;
if( t = local.secondSetting || secondSetting )  entry.secondSetting = t;
if( t = local.thirdSetting  || thirdSetting  )  entry.thirdSetting  = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a module like [xtend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xtend).

It allows you to use an arbitrary number of objects that will be merged into one object. Consider that the right-most object takes precedence over all the others.

This requires your global variables to be grouped into a single object, which is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using a module. Lodash might have something too, but it seems like it doesn't have methods for merging objects whilst skipping undefined values..

Comment: If you are using lodash anyway, try  [_.defaults](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults)